# How to recognize a folder rename in JGit

Tags: git, directory, jgit, mv

`git mv foldera folderb`, results in all the files in `foldera` being moved to `folderb`. Using `DiffFormatter` I can see `DiffEntry` objects for each file.

However, that doesn't tell the whole story. Specificially, from the `DiffEntry` objects I can't determine if `foldera` was renamed to `folderb`, or did `folderb` already exist prior to the commit and the 2 files were individually moved in the commit, leaving `foldera` having 2 fewer files in it.  Is there a different class to inspect the commit to get this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git tracks changes in files, not folders. If you just created `folderb`, git wouldn't recognize it(even if you `git add folderb`). If you moved all the files from `foldera` to `folderb`, git wouldn't know that `foldera` still exists.

In other words, unless there is some plugin that tracks folders in git repositories, you can't discriminate between those two cases - because that information doesn't exist in the repository. Git doesn't know there are `foldera` and `folderb` - all it knows is that there are some files with `foldera/` and `folderb/` in their paths.